# Send Reminder follow ups when due date approaches in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I got an requirement where follow ups to be made automated through excel and reminder emails need to be send via VBA scripts . I got all the information, but sending automated email by clicking on the command button in the excel workbook throws me an error. Kindly help me in this

```
Sub SendReminderMail()
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim MailDest As String

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutLookMailItem
MailDest = ""
For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(13))
If MailDest = "" And Cells(iCounter, 13).Offset(0, -1) = "Send Reminder" Then
MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 13).Value
ElseIf MailDest <> "" And Cells(iCounter, 13).Offset(0, -1) = "Send Reminder" Then
MailDest = MailDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 13).Value
End If
Next iCounter

.BCC = MailDest
.Subject = "Due date approaching"
.Body = "Reminder: Your due date is near approaching . Please ignore if already paid."
.Send
End With

Set OutLookMailItem = Nothing
Set OutLookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have modified my script as this

```
Sub datesexcelvba()
Dim myApp, mymail
Dim mydate1 As Date
Dim mydate2 As Long
Dim datetoday1 As Date
Dim datetoday2 As Long

Dim x As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lastrow

mydate1 = Cells(x, 6).Value
mydate2 = mydate1

Cells(x, 9).Value = mydate2

datetoday1 = Date
datetoday2 = datetoday1

Cells(x, 10).Value = datetoday2

If mydate2 - datetoday2 = 3 Then

Set myApp = CreateObject(Outlook.Application)
Set mymail = myApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
mymail.To = Cells(x, 5).Value

With mymail
.Subject = "Payment Reminder"
.Body = "Your credit card payment is due." & vbCrLf & "Kindly ignore if already paid." & vbCrLf & "Dinesh Takyar"
.Display
‘.Send
End With

Cells(x, 7) = "Yes"
Cells(x, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Cells(x, 7).Font.ColorIndex = 2
Cells(x, 7).Font.Bold = True
Cells(x, 8).Value = mydate2 - datetoday2
End If
Next
Set myApp = Nothing
Set mymail = Nothing

End Sub
```

It shows no error but since , i am unable to send emails. I have done this also in the VB Tools->References->Microsoft Outlook 12.0 object library is checked but it does not work. please help

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot send out a mail item to a number of .BCC recipients without having at least one .To. Set up yourself as the  .To.

Comment: Please help me on how to do that. The Email recipient is added in the worksheet and it need to check that cell and sent email accordingly

Comment: What part or parts of the code do you understand and what parts are you having trouble with?

Comment: MailDest = vbNullString
For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(13))
    If Cells(iCounter, 13).Offset(0, -1) = "Send Reminder" Then till this i got what is happening .  ElseIf Not CBool(InStr(1, MailDest, Chr(64))) Then
            MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 13).Value. This part i am not able to understand.

Comment: a) I have run the code and it worked exactly as expected. b) Perhaps you have not set up programmatic access for your OutLook in OutLook Options.

Comment: Have a look at the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) .

Comment: Can you help me on how to do. I have configured my outlook for gmail

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-customize/how-can-i-change-the-programmatic-access-options/106a6f44-795e-40af-b930-916bcf60ebb4

Comment: @Jeeped It shows run time error. There should be atleast one name in the contact group To,CC,BCC box

Comment: @Jeeped: Outlook cannot recognize one or more names this is the error

Comment: It seems that you are not reading the worksheet values correctly. The values on the worksheet have all be checked haven't they? If not, why are you trying to write a procedure that uses bad data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has been modified and working fine . 
Click on the  Visual basic code environment in excel

First select the outlook library from Tools--> References--> Microsoft outlook 12.0 library or any other versions of outlook library  you have .

```
Sub Email()
'Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookApp
Dim objMail
Dim mydate1 As Date
Dim mydate2 As Long
Dim datetoday1 As Date
Dim datetoday2 As Long
Dim x As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 2 To lastrow

mydate1 = Cells(x, 6).Value
mydate2 = mydate1

Cells(x, 9).Value = mydate2

datetoday1 = Date
datetoday2 = datetoday1

Cells(x, 10).Value = datetoday2

If mydate2 - datetoday2 = 1 Then

'Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
objMail.To = Cells(x, 5).Value
k
With objMail
.Subject = "Payment Reminder"
.Body = "Your payment is due." & vbCrLf & "Kindly ignore if already paid." & vbCrLf & "Hari"
'.Display
.send
End With

Cells(x, 7) = "Yes"
Cells(x, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Cells(x, 7).Font.ColorIndex = 2
Cells(x, 7).Font.Bold = True
Cells(x, 8).Value = mydate2 - datetoday2
End If
Next
Set OutlookApp = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the relevant section of code where you build the MailDest variable with this.

```
MailDest = vbNullString
For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(13))
    If Cells(iCounter, 13).Offset(0, -1) = "Send Reminder" Then
        If Not CBool(InStr(1, .to, Chr(64))) Then
            .to = Cells(iCounter, 13).Value
        ElseIf Not CBool(InStr(1, MailDest, Chr(64))) Then
            MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 13).Value
        Else
            MailDest = MailDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 13).Value
        End If
    End If
Next iCounter
```

The first recipient will go into the `.To` of the mail item. Subsequent recipients will go into the MailDest var which later gets put into `.BCC`.

Comment: Hi, I tried with your code my modifying but since i was thrown up with exception. Can you please help me with alternate script if possible.